# How can I test Component with Tapestry Testify

Tags: tapestry

I am doing some tests with the tapestry-testify librairy. But I have a question about its documentation : http://tapestry.formos.com/nightly/tapestry-testify/testing-components.html

I would like to pass different value to a parameter of my component. 
Could someone explain to me how can i do that.

I have the same project structure as in the documentation.

**myComponent.java**

```java
public class myComponent {    
    @Parameter
    @Property
    private String myParam;
}
```

**myComponent.tml**

```html
<fieldset xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd">
    <p>test ${myParam}</p>
</fieldset>
```

**myComponentDemo.java**

```java
public class MyComponentDemo {
    @Inject
    @Service("myParam")
    @Property
    private String myParam;    
}
```

**myComponentDemo.tml**

```html
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>DayMonthYearDateInputTestPage</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="h2">DayMonthYearDateInputTestPage</h1>

        <div t:type="myC/MyComponent" t:id="myComponent" t:myParam="myParam"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**myComponentTest.java**

```java
import Perso.monAppli.demo.DemoModule;

import com.formos.tapestry.testify.core.ForComponents;
import com.formos.tapestry.testify.core.TapestryTester;
import com.formos.tapestry.testify.junit3.TapestryTest;

public class MyComponentTest extends TapestryTest {

    @ForComponents(value="myParam")
    private String myParam;

    private static final TapestryTester SHARED_TESTER = new TapestryTester("app", DemoModule.class);

    public MyComponentTest() {
        super(SHARED_TESTER);
    }

    @Test
    public void testElementIsOnPage() {
        Document page = tester.renderPage("demo/MyComponentDemo");
        System.out.println("### HTML " + page.getRootElement().getChildMarkup());
        Assert.assertTrue(page.getRootElement().getChildMarkup().contains("testMyParam"));
    }
}
```

Do I have to create a service for passing value to my component ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When Id test that solution, i have got this error message : 
[ERROR] ioc.Registry Service id 'myParam' is not defined by any module.

Comment: Did you created service for myParam in AppModule.java class?
Or try to remove @Inject annotation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of this, but did you try to change name of "myParam"?

For instance:

myComponentDemo.java

```java
@Inject
@Service("myParamService")
@Property
private String myParamValue;
```

myComponentDemo.tml

```html
<div t:type="myC/MyComponent" t:id="myComponent" t:myParam="myParamValue"/>
```

myComponentTest.java

```java
@ForComponents("myParamService")
private String myParam;
```